# Multiple apps on one server with subdomains

Tags: vps, subdomain, dns-hosting

I'd like my VPS to host multiple applications. For instance

- `mydomain.com` (Python Django App)
- `git.mydomain.com` (Gitlab)
- `blog.mydomain.com` (Wordpress)

How can it be achieved to run all these on one physical machine? (Thinking of Heroku-Apps here)

---

Since this question was being put on-hold for being off-topic and the rules say that one should provide at least an "attempted solution", here it is: I've set up Bind9 on my VPS to redirect all sub-domains to the same IP, I could then read the requested sub-domain from the HTTP request in WSGI. I was then thinking of creating a Python Server which redistributes the HTTP requests to applications that listen on different ports (eg. GitLab on 8000, the Django application on 8001, Wordpress on 8002). But that would not allow non-HTTP requests to be correctly forwarded (eg. reading/writing to a Git repository for GitLab).

I thought there must be another way to do it, but I didn't know how to do it. I also didn't have a good keyword like "Named Virtual Servers" for which I could search for, so my search attempts where rather unsatisfying.

Comment: This is precisely what [name-based virtualhosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/index.html) are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apache Virtual Host documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/index.html) can give you a good overview.

Check [all [virtualhost] questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtualhost) for specifics for the specific OS and distribution you are using.

On Debian/Ubuntu style systems you can add your subdomains (or other domains) to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/[YOUR_SUBDOMAIN]` and then run `a2ensite [YOUR_SUBDOMAIN]`. Don't forget to `reload` Apache after changing your settings.

You can easily do the same thing with nginx and other web servers but you're probably better off starting with Apache if you don't have much experience with this stuff.

Comment: Thanks @KasperSouren, I didn't know it was called "Virtual Host".

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Apache2, you can create a virtual host for each.  I prefer to use named virtual hosts so I don't need a new ip address for each.

The way I do it, is to add an include line in the /usr/local/apache/conf/extra/httpd_vhosts.conf file that points to a directory containing all of your virtual host files.

------httpd_vhosts.conf---------

`Listen 80
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/extra/vhosts/*.conf"`

------end-----------------------

You need the Listen 80 before the virtual hosts or you'll get port already in use.

the in the vhosts directory, add your custom virtual host files.

-------vhosts/example.conf--------------

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/drupal7"
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/logs/example.error.log"
    CustomLog "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/logs/example.access.log" "%t %a %>s \"%r\" %b %D"
    <Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/drupal7">
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteBase /
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
    </Directory>
    <Location />
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Location>
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup apache apache
    </IfModule>
    <Directory /usr/local/apache/htdocs/drupal7>
       AllowOverride All
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteBase /
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpg
       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/png
       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/gif
       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/ico
    </Directory>
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
       ExpiresActive On
       ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 days"
       ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 30 days"
       ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 30 days"
       ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 30 days"
       ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 30 days"
       ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 30 days"
       ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 30 days"
       ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 30 days"
       ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 30 days"
       ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 30 days"
       ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 30 days"
       ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 30 days"
       ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 30 days"
       ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 30 days"
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

------end------------------------------

So you'll add a new vhost file for each subdomain that you want to have a separate host for.  Change the ServerName, ServerAlias, <Directory... and <Location directives to match your needs.  i.e.  git.example.com, sub1.example.com, sub2.example.com  etc..

Comment: The above is for Centos VPS.  If your VPS provider is using ubuntu, you need a new VPS provider.